# Get all the names were total purchases are >70% of all the purchases per client

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have information about places and purchases in a table, and I need to find the name of all the places where, for all the clients who purchased in that place, the total of their purchases is at least 70%.

I've already found the answer on python, I've sum the number of purchases per client, then the purchases per client and place, and I've created a new column with the percentage.

So I got something like this:

| client_id | place_name | total purchase | detail purchase | percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | place1 | 10 | 7 | 0.7 |
| 1 | place2 | 10 | 3 | 0.3 |
| 2 | place1 | 5 | 4 | 0.8 |
| 2 | place3 | 5 | 1 | 0.2 |

So, my answer should be place1, since all the purchases in that place all the percentage is

> = 70%.

I've developed this python code to solve it:

```
places = []
for  i in place name:
     if (c[c["place_name"]==i]["percent"]>=0.7).all():
       places.append(i)
```

but now I need to do it in SQl, but I'm not sure if there's a way to get a similar behavior with the function all in SQL
I've been trying this:

```
SELECT place_name 
FROM c
GROUP BY place_name
HAVING total_purchase/detail_purchase >=0.7
```

But, It doesn't work :c
Any help?

Comment: Change the order of numerator and denominator, and add aggregation such that `SUM(detail_purchase/total_purchase )>=.7` after adding `client_id` to the GROUP BY list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table c(client_id int, place_name varchar(50), total_purchase int, detail_purchase int);
 insert into c values(1 ,'place1',  10, 7);
 insert into c values(1 ,'place2',  10, 3);
 insert into c values(2 ,'place1',  5,  4);
 insert into c values(2 ,'place3',  5,  1);
```

Query:

```
 with cte as
 (
   select client_id,place_name,total_purchase,detail_purchase,detail_purchase*1.0/total_purchase percent,
   count( client_id)over (partition by place_name) total_client
   from c a
 )
 select place_name 
 from cte where percent>=0.7
 group by place_name
 having count(client_id)=max(total_client)
```

Output:

| place_name |
| --- |
| place1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e458704de14ad6ba8de2ebeae631a7f0)*

Comment: There is no need for CTE and Windows Function. There are much cleaner solutions for this

Answer (score 1):

Here is a clean solution based on [group by](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-agg.html) and [min](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/functions-aggregate.html) functions

```
select place_name
from c
group by place_name
having min(percent)>=0.7
```

| place_name |
| --- |
| place1 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0d408d39c8d71a4f8baf33afbbfa49ba&hide=1)

Comment: I think that dosn't work due, since if somone has 0.9 and other one has 0,6, the averge is 0.75, but I need it for each person to be >=0.7. 
Sorry if I didn't made it clear on the question

Comment: I changed it to min function so everyone in each place needs to count as at least 70% for the place to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could just use a where statement

```
SELECT place_name
FROM purchases
where (detail_purchase/total_purchase) >=0.7
GROUP BY place_name
```

[db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w4EVh4WrdPJWJBKzqJ8RQb/1)

Comment: I think that this will remove the values in the places where the percent is lower than 0.7, but what I need is to "check if every purchase in that places has a percent of at least 0.7"